# php regex word boundary matching in utf-8

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, pcre, word-boundary

I have the following php code in a utf-8 php file:

```
var_dump(setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'de_DE.utf8', 'German_Germany.utf-8', 'de_DE', 'german'));
var_dump(mb_internal_encoding());
var_dump(mb_internal_encoding('utf-8'));
var_dump(mb_internal_encoding());
var_dump(mb_regex_encoding());
var_dump(mb_regex_encoding('utf-8'));
var_dump(mb_regex_encoding());
var_dump(preg_replace('/\bweiß\b/iu', 'weiss', 'weißbier'));
```

I would like the last regex to replace only full words and not parts of words.

On my windows computer, it returns:

```
string 'German_Germany.1252' (length=19)
string 'ISO-8859-1' (length=10)
boolean true
string 'UTF-8' (length=5)
string 'EUC-JP' (length=6)
boolean true
string 'UTF-8' (length=5)
string 'weißbier' (length=9)
```

On the webserver (linux), I get:

```
string(10) "de_DE.utf8"
string(10) "ISO-8859-1"
bool(true)
string(5) "UTF-8"
string(10) "ISO-8859-1"
bool(true)
string(5) "UTF-8"
string(9) "weissbier"
```

Thus, the regex works as I expected on windows but not on linux.

So the main question is, how should I write my regex to only match at word boundaries?

A secondary questions is how I can let windows know that I want to use utf-8 in my php application.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Even in UTF-8 mode, standard class shorthands like `\w` and `\b` are not Unicode-aware.  You just have to use the Unicode shorthands, as you worked out, but you can make it a little less ugly by using lookarounds instead of alternations:

```
/(?<!\pL)weiß(?!\pL)/u
```

Notice also how I left the curly braces out of the Unicode class shorthands; you can do that when the class name consists of a single letter.

Comment: +1 - `\w` and `\b` appear to work as expected in recent PHP versions but they're definitively not something you can rely on since they'll probably break when you deploy your app.

Comment: Also note the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781898/regex-word-boundary-does-not-work-in-ut8-on-some-servers if you want to use the unicode shorthands!

Answer (score 5):

Guess this was related to **[Bug #52971](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52971)**

> PCRE-Meta-Characters like `\b` `\w` not working with unicode strings.

and **[fixed in PHP 5.3.4](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.4)**

> PCRE extension: **Fixed bug #52971** (*PCRE-Meta-Characters not working with utf-8*).

Answer (score 4):

here is what I have found so far. By rewriting the search and replacement patterns like this:

```
$before = '(^|[^\p{L}])';
$after = '([^\p{L}]|$)';
var_dump(preg_replace('/'.$before.'weiß'.$after.'/iu', '$1weiss$2', 'weißbier'));
// Test some other cases:
var_dump(preg_replace('/'.$before.'weiß'.$after.'/iu', '$1weiss$2', 'weiß'));
var_dump(preg_replace('/'.$before.'weiß'.$after.'/iu', '$1weiss$2', 'weiß bier'));
var_dump(preg_replace('/'.$before.'weiß'.$after.'/iu', '$1weiss$2', ' weiß'));
```

I get the wanted result:

```
string 'weißbier' (length=9)
string 'weiss' (length=5)
string 'weiss bier' (length=10)
string ' weiss' (length=6)
```

on both my windows computer running apache and on the hosted linux webserver running apache.

I assume there is some better way to do this.

Also, I still would like to setlocale my windows computer to utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#89471), that is a bug in PHP. Does using `\W` instead of `\b` give any benefit?

Comment: Yes it was, 10 years ago.

Comment: Yes they were. Better now?