# regex word boundary does not work in utf8 on some servers

Tags: php, regex

I have a weird problem. consider this short code:

```
<?php
$reg =  '/(?<!\pL)(test)(?!\pL)/u';
$text='This is a test text';
$replace = 'test_replaced';

$newtext = preg_replace($reg, $replace, $text);

echo "Error: ".preg_last_error()."\nResult: ".$newtext."\n";

?>
```

On some servers the UTF8 boundary matching does not work. I get

```
Error: 0
Result:
```

On majority servers everything works normally:

```
Error: 0
Result: This is a test_replaced text
```

There seems to be a problem with word boundary as when I use `\b` instead the code works.

Both servers use php 5.2.13. Any clues what might be wrong and how to get around it?

Comment: And why don't you use `\b` for this? How many servers do you have? Two or more?

Comment: \b does not work with UTF8. I have the issue on two servers (out of hundreds)

Comment: This was probably related to a [bug which was fixed in PHP 5.3.4](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41074513/5527985)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment [here](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php#96479) seems to suggest that PCRE needs to be compiled with `--enable-unicode-properties`.