# string processing-getting 20 words from a string

Tags: php

I would like to know what method is good to get the first 20 words from an english sentence. I need to analyze its subject and verb before processing further. Because there are sentences that are useless so I don't need to analyze them, dump them instead :-D

Ok It's always better for the starter to start first (pss is there a proverb or saying that fits well my claim here in English - I am a very active English learner ;-D)

Here you go:

```
$array=explode($string," ");
$con=$array[0];
$i=0;
foreach($array as $v)
{
  if($i++ == 20){break;}
  $con.=" ".$v[i];
}
```

Oh yezzz, Anyone can help with neater function or method please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_slice()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) will slice the array for you. Just specify the beginning and end elements:

```
$words = explode($string, ' ');
$firstTwenty = array_slice($words, 0, 20);
```

If you want to get really compact (but a little less readable), do this instead:

```
$twentyWords= array_slice(explode($string, ' '), 0, 20);
```

`$twentyWords` will be an array. If you want to concatenate it back into a string, just use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$newString = implode(' ', $twentyWords);
```

Comment: +1 good explanation; note that `$twentyWords` will be an array, you may want to `implode()` if you are looking for a string

Answer (score 1):

You can use welknown php function `substr` Here is the usage...

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function...

```
$first_twenty_words = wordlimit($string, 20);

function wordlimit($string, $length = 20) 
{ 
   $words = explode(' ', $string); 
   if (count($words) > $length) 
       return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $length)); 
   else 
       return $string; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will split words using spaces as word boundaries and return the first 20:

```
implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $sentence), 0, 20));
```

There are some occasions where word boundaries may not be spaces; you could also look at [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and `\b`.

> Credit: [How to select first 10 words of a sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956610/how-to-select-first-10-words-of-a-sentence)

Answer (score 0):

By this way you can get first 20 words of any string:

```
    $str = "this is a string and i want to slice string after 20 words.
this is a string and i want to slice string after 20 words";

    $strArray = explode(" ",$str);
    $strArray = array_slice($strArray,0 , 20);
    $string =  implode(" ",$strArray);
    echo $string;
```