# Load in words, not letters [WordPress/PHP]

Tags: php, string, wordpress, function, content-management-system

I hope someone can help me out.

I'm working on a website where I installed Wordpress. On the frontpage I have a small div where I want to output the first 10 words from another page with pageID.
At the moment it's almost working but instead of loading in 10 words it's loading in 10 letters.

**Example:**
*Instead of:* Hello my name is Erwin and this is a test
*It loads:* Hello my nam

What am I doing wrong?

**I Use the following php in functions.php:**

```
if(!function_exists('getPageContent'))
{
    function getPageContent($pageId,$num_words)
    {
        if(!is_numeric($pageId))
        {
            return;
        }
        global $wpdb;
        $nsquery = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ' . $wpdb->posts .
        ' WHERE ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID=' . $pageId;
        $post_data = $wpdb->get_results($nsquery);
        if(!empty($post_data))
        {
            foreach($post_data as $post)
            {
                $text_out=nl2br($post->post_content);
                $text_out=str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text_out);
                $text_out = strip_tags($text_out);
                return substr($text_out,0,$num_words);

            }
        }
    }}
```

**And I use the following string to load in the content:**
*(Where 89 is my Page ID)*

```
echo getPageContent(89,10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to select first 10 words of a sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956610/how-to-select-first-10-words-of-a-sentence) - same question. Just use `implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $text_out), 0, $num_words));` instead of `substr($text_out,0,$num_words);`

Comment: this is the best and fastest solution in combination with the code I posted above, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This will extract first 10 words of your string

```
$text_out = "Hello my name is Erwin and this is a test and this is another test";
$num_words = 10;
echo implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $text_out), 0, $num_words));
```

**Output**

```
Hello my name is Erwin and this is a test
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer, but its a different problem. I know I have to change the 10 to 32 to load in the first 32 letters but what I want is that I can load in the first words. (because the text in the other page can be different everyday and I dont want to count the letters all the time.. I just want that the script automatic loads in the first words :)

Comment: use `strlen` function it will automatically count the length of string, here is the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: so you want only 1st word as output?

Comment: the first 10 words as output :)

Comment: @ErwinvanEkeren check my edited answer, it will help you to extract first 10 words of string

Answer (score 0):

There is a function from wordpress:

```
the_excerpt();
```

which does that exactly. It shows ... the excerpt of the article or page and a link at the end. You can customize the length using the argument `the_excerpt($length)` modifiing the function a bit.

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I found that one too but somehow I can't connect it to a certain pageID. It just loads in the first 10 words of the page where i'm currently on and it doesn't ouput the content from another page

Comment: because you probably have to load the file containing the function or something like that.

Comment: my skills with php are the low for what you just said haha!

Answer (score 0):

Here `$num_words = 10`

it means `substr` breaks the string from character `0 to 10`

if you want whole string then you have to echo

```
echo getPageContent(89,32);
```