# PHP - split a string using str_word_count as opposed to preg_replace

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to split long strings into 2 seperate pieces depending on varying word counts (some strings i would like split at 2 words, maybe other ones at 4, etc.) so that I can wrap the second split with a  tag.

For example:

```
<?php $string = 'A long title is not great for the world to read";<?php>
<h1><?php echo $string;?></h1>
```

However, would prefer the output to be:

```
<h1>A long title <span>is not great for the world to read</span></h1>
```

I've almost successfully used this method, but I was having problems with the regex throwing fits when there were quotations or apostrophes in the string and figured maybe it's easier to just use `str_word_count` as it's also less taxing on the server:

```
function get_snippet($str, $wordCount) {
    $arr = preg_split(
        '/(?<=\w)\b/', 
        $str, 
        $wordCount*2+1, 
        PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
    );

    $first = implode('', array_slice($arr, 0, $wordCount));
    $last = implode('', array_slice($arr, $wordCount));

    return $first.'<span>'.$last.'</span>';
}

<h1>
    <?php $string = get_the_title(); echo get_snippet($string, 3);?>
</h1>
```

This code was modified from here:
[How to select first 10 words of a sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956610/how-to-select-first-10-words-of-a-sentence#answer-12445298)

Answer (score 1):

You could go for the first space after a number of characters like this...

```
<?php
$string = "A long title is not great for the world to read.";
$splitPosition = strpos($string, " ", 10);
print "<h1>" . substr($string, 0, $splitPosition) . "<span>" . substr($string, $splitPosition) . "</span></h1>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get your first part and then use [`ltrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) to trim it from our main string.
Or you could use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) twice for the first and last part of your string.

Comment: But wouldn't that be counting actual characters, as opposed to words?

Answer (score 0):

This is my two cents. mb_substr function from php manual.

```
    $string = "A long title is not great for the world to read";
    echo "<h1>".mb_substr($string,0,13);."<span>".mb_substr($string,13,strlen($string))."</span></h1>";
```