# preg_match_all matches English words perfectly but no luck with Hebrew words

Tags: php, mysql, hebrew

I m trying to match the Hebrew banned words retrieved from the mysql db table with Hebrew string in `$_POST['content']`, for English words (if used in Hebrew string `$_POST['content']`) its giving the match but for Hebrew words no luck. Can you help me to modify the code below to search a banned Hebrew word in a given string?  All the source of data has been checked its in UTF-8 format.

```
<?

$banned_words=array();
while($loc=mysql_fetch_array($loc_query))
{
    $banned_words[$k]=stripslashes(utf8_decode($loc["sb_word"]));
    $k=$k+1;
}

$matches = array();
$matchFound = preg_match_all(
    "/\b(" . implode($banned_words,"|") . ")\b/u", 
    $_POST['content'], 
    $matches
    );

if ($matchFound)
{  
    $words = array_unique($matches[0]);   
    $word_status=1;
    }
?>
```

Comment: [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) works the other way round. You need to give the glue character first, then the array variable.

Comment: @mario implode() can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either order. For consistency with explode(), however, it may be less confusing to use the documented order of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` is not unicode-aware, you should use [Unicode character properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2449017/258674) for some help